# roots of quartic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given a polynomial  $$x^4 - px^3 +px -1=0$$ where $p>0$. I tried to find the roots using the general Quartic formulas but the derivation gets complex. I need to get to  show that one of the roots is $$x_0={1\over 2}[p+ \sqrt{(p^2-4)}]$$ any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the quartic is $(x^4-1)-px(x^2-1)$. Has this an obvious factorisation?

Comment: you know you can get MathJax to work in comments as well right ?

Comment: thats more than enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By inspection, $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are roots. Divide by $x^2-1$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write your equation in the form:
$$x^4-1-px(x^2-1)=0$$ and further $$(x^2-1)(x^2+1)-px(x^2-1)=0$$